# What's the difference between xorg.conf, xset and xinput set?

Tags: linux, xorg

I don't understand why with xset and xorg.conf there are two things with exactly the same purpose but totally different options? Why are there two and not one? Why can't their parameters have the same names? And even in xorg.conf itself there are multiple options with different names and the same effect. Why is that so chaotic?

For example I can deactivate my mouse acceleration in xorg.conf with

```
Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
```

or with

```
xset m 0 0
```

I use Arch Linux with Gnome 3 and Linux Kernel 3.0.26-1-lts.

Comment: P.S.: Please write why you downvoted it. I googled for it but couldn't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: What's the specific programming problem you're trying to solve here? This is a rant, not a question. (it's also probably off-topic)

Comment: To start programming I want to adjust my mouse sensitivity to 900 dpi and that's why I want to know where I should do it - in xset, xorg.conf or xinput set-props. P.S.: Also only because you perceive it as a rant doesn't mean it is one. I only want to know WHY it is like this (historical reasons, maybe there is some sense in it and I just didn't find it yet).

Comment: I agree this question sounds more like a rant than a question. To avoid this in the future, please give examples demonstrating each of things you claim. Still, it is a valid question IMHO: even if you just read the question title and ignore the content, it looks like a valid question.

Answer (score 10):

The `xorg.conf` file is used to set the configuration that will be in place when you start X. After you start X, changing `xorg.conf` won't make any difference (unless you restart X, but that requires a log out).

The `xset` and `xinput` commands are used to change the configuration *after* you start X. This means that even though there's a default option inside `xorg.conf`, you (or your toolkit) can change this default at run-time. You can keep changing your options without the need to log out.

That explained the difference between `xorg.conf` and the runtime apps (like `xset` and `xinput`). The difference between `xset` and `xinput` is written in `xset`'s manpage:

```
The setting is applied to  all  connected  pointing
devices.  xinput(1)  should be used if you need device-specific
settings.
```

You mention that in `xorg.conf` there are multiple options with different names and the same effect. I'd like to see an example. I know some options have some "intersection", but they are usually meant for different purposes.

Comment: An example for multiple options with the same effect would be "Resolution" and "Sensitivity" which I have read would set the DPI of a mouse. Neither work for me, however.

Answer (score 4):

`xorg.conf` is really a legacy configuration system which has been around for ever.  The downside of it is that you have to restart X for the settings to take effect.  However it's well integrated in the X server and relatively easy to add new settings to.

But current day X developers tend to prefer interfaces that permit changing X settings on the fly while X is running.  That generally requires creation of APIs/protocols and X extensions to implement an interface that can be used from userspace.  xinput, xrandr, xset, and so on are all examples of this type of on-the-fly customization.